# Lunching PlantUML JAR fails via terminal

Tags: java, plantuml

I downloaded the PlantUML and tryed to run it via Terminal with the command "java -jar /home/Victor/programms/plantUML/plantuml.jar".

But it always throws the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException
>       at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:204)
>       at java.awt.Window.(Window.java:536)
>       at java.awt.Frame.(`Frame`.java:420)
>       at javax.swing.JFrame.(JFrame.java:233)
>       at net.sourceforge.plantuml.swing.MainWindow2.(MainWindow2.java:154)
>       at net.sourceforge.plantuml.Run.main(Run.java:131)

The wired things is, when I import the jar to a project into IntelliJ and run it there, it works totally fine. 
What am I missing, what am I doing wrong.
I'm using Fedora (Linux)

Answer (score 2):

Given the `HeadlessException` it appears that your default Java installation is a headless version (i.e. has no support for keyboard, display, etc.); whereas, your IntelliJ installation is using a different Java installation.

Type `java -version` to see what information it returns. I'd expect that it might be something to the tune of `openjdk-headless`. You may also want to check what other Java installations are available with `alternatives --config java` and select a more suitable one, if given.

If `alternatives` does not show a full version installation, you can either: 1) add the IntelliJ installation with `alternatives set java <path_to_ij_install>` or 2) use `yum` to install a full version.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I needed to pass '-pipe' option to plantuml as follows when passing text input from stdin:

> cat INPUT.txt | java -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/tmp -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar /PATH/TO/plantuml.jar -pipe ...